# GrabDuck.com: full-text search and recommendations on your StackOverflow Favorites

Tags: app, website

### Screenshots

#### Synchronized with StackOverflow bookmarks and tags

[image: GrabDuck: Bookmarks and tags synchronized with StackOverflow]

#### Setting up sync with StackOverflow

[image: GrabDuck setting up sync with StackOverflow]

[image: GrabDuck configuring the StackOverflow sync]

### About

GrabDuck is the only bookmarking service that offers full text search on your bookmarks.

Set up automatic synchronization with dozens of StackExchange websites such as StackOverflow, and get access to all your tags and perform full-text search on your saved favorites from the StackExchange websites at GrabDuck.

#### License

The Service is in testing phase. During this period, all service functions are free of charge!

#### Website

[GrabDuck.com](http://grabduck.com)

#### Platform

Website. Extensions for Chrome & FireFox for adding new bookmarks are available.

### Contact

grabduck@gmail.com | https://twitter.com/GrabDuck

Comment: Well I dont think so. What we offer as one of the features is periodicall sync with user's account favorites from dozen of StackExchange websites (user can set it up in her account by providing her user id) and after that user's favorites are available for full text searching.For that we are using Stack API and here in the post we are talking only about this "sync" possibility completely related to SO.

Comment: Is this still going ?  Is it still free ?